# Rust `find_any` keeps searching

Tags: rust, parallel-processing

I'm trying to brute-force and find `x` from `g^x = y (mod p)`, given that I know that `x` is only a "few" bits.

```rust
use num_bigint::BigUint;
use num_traits::One;
use rayon::prelude::*;
use std::sync::Mutex;

fn main() {
    let p = BigUint::parse_bytes("531137992816767098689588206552468627329593117727031923199444138200403559860852242739162502265229285668889329486246501015346579337652707239409519978766587351943831270835393219031728127"
        .as_bytes(), 10).unwrap();
    let g = BigUint::parse_bytes("743488989946216334211646350465118756727157777337013657445667148279632819469843031446430723942629760903918287800011367316376"
        .as_bytes(), 10).unwrap();
    let y = BigUint::parse_bytes("85300193795644893333630947242400469685524126293619036977651049331711403849653080708338436527820826037193273430333874138094661788038445049976895820193634304228963983382234907450594225"
        .as_bytes(), 10).unwrap();

    println!("g: {}", g);
    println!("y: {}", y);

    // Brute force y = g^x
    let size = BigUint::from(2u32).pow(20);
    let num_cores = 8 as usize;
    let chunk_size = &size / num_cores;

    let num = Mutex::new(None);
    (0..num_cores)
        .into_par_iter()
        .find_any(|&core_idx| {
            let start = chunk_size.clone() * core_idx;
            let end = if core_idx == num_cores - 1 {
                size.clone()
            } else {
                start.clone() + chunk_size.clone()
            };

            let mut x = start.clone();
            while x < end {
                let y_candidate = g.modpow(&x, &p);

                // Check if g^x == y
                if y_candidate == y {
                    println!("Found x: {}", x);
                    *num.lock().unwrap() = Some(x.clone());

                    return true;
                }

                x += BigUint::one();
            }

            false
        });

    if let Some(x) = num.lock().unwrap().clone() {
        println!("Found num: {}", x);

    } else {
        println!("x not found in the specified range.");
    };
}
```

The problem I'm facing is that although one thread finds `x`, the rest keep searching. I guess `find_any` does not guarantee that the other threads will stop. Any comments on how to optimize this? [Source](https://docs.rs/rayon/latest/rayon/iter/trait.ParallelIterator.html#method.find_any):

> "Searches for some item in the parallel iterator that matches the given predicate and returns it. This operation is similar to find on sequential iterators but the item returned may not be the first one in the parallel sequence which matches, since we search the entire sequence in parallel.

> Once a match is found, we will attempt to stop processing the rest of the items in the iterator as soon as possible (just as find stops iterating once a match is found)."

Comment: From first glance, this code looks a little convoluted. It's likely you should be taking a different approach. Please provide all of the code necessary to reproduce this issue you're seeing as part of a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: It's also unclear from your question whether `find_any` hangs forever, or whether the threads involved just keep searching a little longer than necessary. Please specify.

Comment: `(0..num_cores).into_par_iter()` is almost always an anti-pattern.

Comment: Thanks for your quick responses, updated the code so you can run it. @PitaJ It just hangs forever, not just a little longer than necessary. Also, why would `into_par_iter()` be an anti-pattern?

Comment: It did eventually complete for me, printing `Found num: 12`. What output do you get?

Comment: It's not `into_par_iter()` that's the anti-pattern, it's iterating over the number of cores. You should let rayon do this for you: `(0..size).into_par_iter()`.

Comment: So it should be printing `Found x: 12` when one thread finds it and `Found num: 12` when all are done. But if you observe the outputs, the `Found x: 12` is almost instant while the second print takes a while, indicating that the other threads exhaust all the search space.

Do you have any suggestions on how to improve this code?

Comment: I'm working on an answer for you.

Comment: Thanks again for your time, appreciate it!

Comment: Well, you parallel iterate without communicating to the other threads that the iteration should be aborted when one element has been found. The other iterator threads do not know that one thread found the matching item and keep searching until they find the desired element or their search space has been exhausted. You need inter-thread communication in order to signal to the other threads that they can abort iteration once one thread finds an element, e.g. by using an atomic bool and a `take_while` on the parallelized iterators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be simplified quite a bit by just parallel iterating over the search range directly, as long as your maximum `x` value fits within a `u64` or even `u128`.

### (1) Simply parallel

```
use num_bigint::BigUint;
use num_traits::One;
use rayon::prelude::*;
use std::sync::Mutex;

fn main() {
    let p = BigUint::parse_bytes("531137992816767098689588206552468627329593117727031923199444138200403559860852242739162502265229285668889329486246501015346579337652707239409519978766587351943831270835393219031728127"
        .as_bytes(), 10).unwrap();
    let g = BigUint::parse_bytes("743488989946216334211646350465118756727157777337013657445667148279632819469843031446430723942629760903918287800011367316376"
        .as_bytes(), 10).unwrap();
    let y = BigUint::parse_bytes("85300193795644893333630947242400469685524126293619036977651049331711403849653080708338436527820826037193273430333874138094661788038445049976895820193634304228963983382234907450594225"
        .as_bytes(), 10).unwrap();

    println!("g: {}", g);
    println!("y: {}", y);

    // Brute force y = g^x
    let size = 2_u64.pow(20);

    let num = (0..size)
        .into_par_iter()
        .map(|n| BigUint::from(n))
        .find_any(|x| {
            let y_candidate = g.modpow(&x, &p);

            // Check if g^x == y
            if y_candidate == y {
                println!("Found x: {}", x);
                true
            } else {
                false
            }
        });

    if let Some(x) = num.clone() {
        println!("Found num: {}", x);
    } else {
        println!("x not found in the specified range.");
    };
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3bbe7d85221d7fdc0a8f04e30f62fae9)

### (2) Chunked processing

But it might be more performant to chunk the calculation. Instead of one chunk per core as you were doing, use a set chunk size that's small enough so as to not be too noticeable:

```
use num_bigint::BigUint;
use rayon::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    let p = BigUint::parse_bytes("531137992816767098689588206552468627329593117727031923199444138200403559860852242739162502265229285668889329486246501015346579337652707239409519978766587351943831270835393219031728127"
        .as_bytes(), 10).unwrap();
    let g = BigUint::parse_bytes("743488989946216334211646350465118756727157777337013657445667148279632819469843031446430723942629760903918287800011367316376"
        .as_bytes(), 10).unwrap();
    let y = BigUint::parse_bytes("85300193795644893333630947242400469685524126293619036977651049331711403849653080708338436527820826037193273430333874138094661788038445049976895820193634304228963983382234907450594225"
        .as_bytes(), 10).unwrap();

    println!("g: {}", g);
    println!("y: {}", y);

    // Brute force y = g^x
    let size = BigUint::from(2_u32).pow(20);
    let min_chunk_size: usize = 1000;

    // Ensure that we don't have more than `usize::MAX` chunks
    let chunk_size = (&size / usize::MAX).max(BigUint::from(min_chunk_size));
    let chunk_count: usize = (&size / &chunk_size).try_into().unwrap();

    let num = (0..chunk_count)
        .into_par_iter()
        .find_map_any(|chunk| {
            let start = &chunk_size * chunk;
            let end = if chunk + 1 == chunk_count {
                size.clone()
            } else {
                &start + &chunk_size
            };

            let mut x = start;
            while x < end {
                let y_candidate = g.modpow(&x, &p);

                // Check if g^x == y
                if y_candidate == y {
                    println!("Found x: {}", x);
                    return Some(x);
                }

                x += 1_u8;
            }

            None
        });

    if let Some(x) = num.clone() {
        println!("Found num: {}", x);
    } else {
        println!("x not found in the specified range.");
    };
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8b8221ac8943189d3a5838bf0277703d)

This also allows you to set `size` as a `BigUint`, meaning your `x` range is unbounded. Though if `size > usize::MAX * 1000`, the chunk size (and therefore delay after finding the answer) will start increasing.

### (3) Atomic flag

You can set an atomic when the answer is found and check that atomic in the loop. This allows you to stop almost immediately, even with very large chunk sizes.

```
use std::sync::atomic::{AtomicBool, Ordering};
use num_bigint::BigUint;
use rayon::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    let p = BigUint::parse_bytes("531137992816767098689588206552468627329593117727031923199444138200403559860852242739162502265229285668889329486246501015346579337652707239409519978766587351943831270835393219031728127"
        .as_bytes(), 10).unwrap();
    let g = BigUint::parse_bytes("743488989946216334211646350465118756727157777337013657445667148279632819469843031446430723942629760903918287800011367316376"
        .as_bytes(), 10).unwrap();
    let y = BigUint::parse_bytes("85300193795644893333630947242400469685524126293619036977651049331711403849653080708338436527820826037193273430333874138094661788038445049976895820193634304228963983382234907450594225"
        .as_bytes(), 10).unwrap();

    println!("g: {}", g);
    println!("y: {}", y);

    // Brute force y = g^x
    let zero = BigUint::from(0_u32);
    let size = BigUint::from(2_u32).pow(20);
    let chunk_count: usize = 8;
    let chunk_size = &size / &chunk_count;

    let found = AtomicBool::new(false);

    let num = (0..chunk_count)
        .into_par_iter()
        .find_map_any(|chunk| {
            let start = &chunk_size * chunk;
            let end = if chunk + 1 == chunk_count {
                size.clone()
            } else {
                &start + &chunk_size
            };

            let mut x = start;
            while x < end {
                // Stop if the answer was found
                // Check infrequently to as to amortize the atomic read
                if &x % 100_u32 == zero {
                    if found.load(Ordering::Relaxed) {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                let y_candidate = g.modpow(&x, &p);

                // Check if g^x == y
                if y_candidate == y {
                    println!("Found x: {}", x);
                    found.store(true, Ordering::Relaxed);
                    return Some(x);
                }

                x += 1_u8;
            }

            None
        });

    if let Some(x) = num.clone() {
        println!("Found num: {}", x);
    } else {
        println!("x not found in the specified range.");
    };
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d36e7beb2d2462d5dc8e48d07078b9ae)

If you expect the answer to be somewhere near the beginning of the range, I would recommend using far more chunks than you have processing cores. This prevents wasting so much processing power on chunks nowhere close to the answer.

Comment: Thanks, indeed this looks cleaner but this will not work if the size is `BigUint` since the `..` is not supported. Actually, that was my starting point :)

Comment: Still working on it

Comment: Are you really going to be searching over spaces where `x >= 2.pow(128)`?

Comment: Well, no. I was trying to generalize it but you make a great point.

Comment: @m0ur added a couple alternatives for you

Comment: That's very thorough, thank you.